# Select only the rows with the latest date in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I only want the latest date for each row (house) the number of entries per house varies sometimes there might be one sale sometimes multiple.

```
Date of sale | house number | street | price |uniqueref
-------------|--------------|--------|-------|----------
15-04-1990   |1             |castle  |100000-| 1xzytt   
15-04-1995   |1             |castle  |200000-| 2jhgkj
15-04-2005   |1             |castle  |800000-| 3sdfsdf
15-04-1995   |2             |castle  |200000-| 2jhgkj
15-04-2005   |2             |castle  |800000-| 3sdfsdf
```

What I have working is as follows

Creating `VIEW` as (v_orderedhouses) `ORDER BY` house number, street with date ordered on `DESC`so that latest date is first returned.

I then feed that into another `VIEW` (v_latesthouses) using `DISTINCT ON` (house number, street). Which gives me;

```
Date of sale | house number | street | price |uniqueref
-------------|--------------|--------|-------|----------
15-04-2005   |1             |castle  |800000-| 3sdfsdf
15-04-2005   |2             |castle  |800000-| 3sdfsdf
```

This works but seems like there should be a more elegant solution. Can I get to the filtered view in one step?

Comment: FYI http://rextester.com/ELL6912 - you'll find that the using `distinct on` is significant faster (and shorter).

Comment: Wow, mind blown. Took a while to compile the index but after that 20s to create a materialized view.  As a newb what role is creating a custom index having?

Comment: Can you supply that as the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number` for this

```
select  * from (
   select your_table.*, row_number() over(partition by house_number order by Date_of_sale desc) as rn from your_table
) tt
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Can i partition by col1 and col2 and col3? There are multiple houses numbered 1 so need to make sure i catch all

Comment: @mappingdom - Yes you can partition by multiple columns, like: `...partition by col1, col2, col3 ...`

Comment: Thank you, interestingly that executes slightly slower at 358.9 versus 316.5. It's much quicker to write though!

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to create a bunch of views, just:

```
select distinct on(street, house_number)
  *
from your_table
order by
  street, house_number, -- those fields should be in the "order by" clause because it is in the "distinct on" expression
  date_of_sale desc;
```

To make this query faster you could to create an index according to the `order by`:

```
create index index_name on your_table(street, house_number, date_of_sale desc);
```

Do not forget to [`analyse`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-analyze.html) your tables regularly (depending on the grown speed):

```
analyse your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and it works fast(is a generic solution, as far as I tested every database software can do this):

```
SELECT t1.date_of_sale, t1.house_number
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (t2.house_number = t1.house_number AND t2.date_of_sale>t1.date_of_sale)
WHERE t2.pk IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.date_of_sale, t1.house_number
```